# Error adding textView to RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-group

i'll get to the point immediately, this is my code:

```
 RadioButton[] rb=new RadioButton[n*3];

           RadioGroup[] rg=new RadioGroup[n];
           for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
           {
               rg[i] = new RadioGroup(MainActivity.this);
               rg[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
               rg[i].setId(i);
               //rg[i].addView(textView); doesn't work with this
               for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
               {
                   rb[i*3+j]=new RadioButton(MainActivity.this);
                   rb[i*3+j].setId(i*3+j);
                   rb[i*3+j].setText("something");
                   rg[i].addView(rb[i*3+j]);
               }
               myLayout.addView(rg[i]);
           }
```

the code works fine without the line `rg[i].addView(textView);`, but when i put that line the application force closes... What's the problem? How can i put this textview into this group?

Comment: What's the problem? Look at your logcat. Still if you can't solve it then post the logcat here.

Comment: where do u create the textview.. are you sure textview is not null

Comment: looks like that's the problem, i'll just check my code again

Comment: sry ppl, i made a stupid mistake, i actually didn't create textView
so i added this tv=new TextView(MainActivity.this);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your textView is null when your are trying to add it. Can you provide complete logcat trace.